# How do I FULLY remove a language in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

I used Rufus to create a Windows 11 installation media, maybe I missed the setting somewhere, but it got created as an EN-GB (United Kingdom). I'm too far gone into installing software and customizing settings to redo it from scratch.

This is what I've done so far:

- installed EN-US
- fixed default install language in the registry
- removed EN-GB from Language settings
- uninstalled any remaining EN-GB components in Add/Remove
- Powershell is only showing EN-US at this time

However, my registry and drive are still littered with EN-GB registry keys and files. I tried manually deleting some of the EN-GB directories, but they come back with "sfc /scannow".

I also tried kicking off the LanguageComponentInstaller Uninstallation task, but that didn't do anything.

Disk Clean Up also doesn't remove them.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151028/discussion-on-question-by-sledgehammer-how-do-i-fully-remove-a-language-in-windo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.